# Does the eye recieve more blue light from being on a laptop screen, or from being outside on a sunny day?

Tags: visible-light

I've been looking for an answer to this, but all that I've been able to find are comparisons between looking at a typical laptop as compared to looking at the sun, but if you're outside on a sunny day, you aren't just going to be staring at the sun the whole time.

I'm interested in this primarily for its relevance to the [idea that blue light damages the eyes](https://www.allaboutvision.com/cvs/blue-light.htm#:%7E:text=Blue%20light%20exposure%20may%20increase,sensitive%20cells%20in%20the%20retina.) (separate from circadian rhythm considerations), but if this is the case, it seems like the advice should be to avoid going outside, rather than to avoid looking at screens.

Comment: I really doubt it. The sun is friggin' bright. Can you see your smartphone or laptop screen outside at maximum brightness even on a cloudy day? Not really.

Comment: @DKNguyen I also believe that to be the case, but I want to be able to prove it, and I don't know enough about light physics to even know where to begin.

Comment: Well to prove it you would need a light meter or a simple light detection circuit but that requires a bit of knowledge.

Comment: Note that, in accordance with the first answer, the title is a bit misleading.  The *eye* receives *far far far* more blue light from the sun.  However, if you are specifically looking at blue light that reaches the retina, after the pupil has controlled light input, its a more complicated story.

Answer (score 1):

Outside sunlight must have more intensity across the visible light spectrum. However, eyes adapt to dark environments (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptation_(eye)), so it might still be more harmful to have a larger concentration in the blue-light range when the overall brightness is much lower. It probably would need more experiments to find out. But in any case, we should wear sunglasses if we are staying in the sun for long:).